# 2SLS with endogenous interaction terms

Tags: econometrics

Suppose I have a regression model:
$$y_{i}=x_{1i}\beta_{1}+x_{1i}D_{i}\beta_{2}+\epsilon
$$
 where $\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon_{i}|x_{i}\right]\neq0$ , and there
is a problem of endogeneity. In the above, think of the dummy variable
being equal to $1$ when $i$ is male. As such, this model allows
for a differential effect of $x_{1i}$ on $y_{i}$, if the individual
is a male or female. In order to obtain consistent estimates, suppose
I have an instrument $z_{1i}$, which is both a relevant instrument
for $x_{1i}$, and satisfies the exclusion restriction (such that
$cov(z_{i},\epsilon_{i})=0).$ If there were no interaction term,
it would be trivial to estimate the above using Two stage least squares,
or simply just computing:
$$
\hat{\beta}=\left(\boldsymbol{z'}x\right)^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol{z'y}\right)
$$

However, the complication arises due to the interaction term. How
would I go about obtaining estimates for both $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$?
One option is to construct another instrument $D_{i}Z_{1i}$. Would
such a procedure be valid?

Comment: In your model, you have an interaction term but do not include all constitutive terms... why?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18869)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the original regressor matrix and $Z = [z \;\; zd]$ be the intstruments matrix, and consider the IV estimator

$$\hat \beta_{IV} = (Z'X)^{-1}Z'y = (Z'X)^{-1}Z'(X\beta + u) = \beta + (Z'X)^{-1}Z'u$$

As long as the things that are included in $Z$ are orthogonal to the error term, we get consistency... provided that $Z'X$ remains invertible, something that you can easily check in your case.

Comment: Thank you. With regards to the projection of X and XD in the first stage, would they each be projected onto Z and ZD in order to obtain fitted values?

Comment: @ChinG If I understand your question correctly, fitted values for the dependent variable should be obtained by using $x_i$ and $d_i$, alongside the IV estimates.

Comment: I think I was not clear in my question: X is endogenous, so I assume so is XD. I only have one instrument Z. It seems according to your response that I can use ZD as an instrument as well. However, in the first stage, will I regress X on Z and ZD in one regression, and XD on Z and ZD in the second? This way I will obtain fitted values for X and XD as separate regressions on both instruments in the first stage. Thereafter I use these fitted values on the RHS in the second.  I feel as if I am missing something basic. Thanks a lot @Alecos Papadopoulos

Comment: @ChinG We do not apply 2SLS here, especially since you have only one instrument. My answer deals with a one-stage estimator.